# Using PHP namespaces in included files

Tags: php, namespaces

I try to use namespaces with included files:

```
<?php
  namespace MyNamespace;

  function foo() {
    echo 'Test';
  }

  include( 'otherfile.php' );
?>
```

Inside ***otherfile.php*** is a `<?php foo(); ?>;` and I would like too see **"Test"** as output of it.

Is there any chance to realize that, without modifying that other file?

My wish: I would like to replace an existing file inside the code of an external library. I don't want to modify that code, since I expect to get further updates there.

Comment: why won't you use composer and its autloading feature?

Comment: autoloading means to define a function while it will be called without defining it before. But the function I want to replace will be definded. (Thank you for teaching the autoload feature to me, I didn't know it before.)

Answer (score 0):

No, it's not possible. You're defining the function `MyNamespace\foo`. The included file is calling the function `foo`. There's no way to change the meaning of what `foo()` refers to without altering the code in that file. If you want to replace the function `foo`, your only real hope is to define your own `function foo` (no namespace) and avoid loading the other implementation of that function. If not this, it's things like [`runkit`](https://www.php.net/runkit), which you don't really want to have to resort to.

Comment: I can't avoid the loading of the implementation of the other function without modifying that code. And if I place my own function before of the `include`, I get a ***fatal error***. As far as I know, I can't catch fatal errors. The external library has more than 500 files ... so now way to modify code inside of it.

Comment: Yeah, you're in a bit of a pickle then…